# Kafka Serializers vs Spring Message Converters in DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm a little confused by the serializers and message converters in spring-kafka. When should the Spring message converters be used and when only the Kafka serializers? As far as I could see in Spring the prefered way would be to configure the Kafka clients key/value serializer with `StringSerializer` and then configure a message converter on the `KafkaTemplate` for the actual POJO to string conversion. Is that correct?

I'm stuck trying to configure a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` which should send messages to DLT for derialization errors as well as for any error while processing the deserialized message. The problem is that I need a `JsonSerializer` when the message was already deserialized but only a simple `StringSerializer` when the message could not be deserialized. Any ideas how to configure that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message conversion in the template only applies to the `send()` method that takes a `Message<?>`.

Use one of the DLPR constructors that takes a map of templates:

```java
    /**
     * Create an instance with the provided templates and a default destination resolving
     * function that returns a TopicPartition based on the original topic (appended with
     * ".DLT") from the failed record, and the same partition as the failed record.
     * Therefore the dead-letter topic must have at least as many partitions as the
     * original topic. The templates map keys are classes and the value the corresponding
     * template to use for objects (producer record values) of that type. A
     * {@link java.util.LinkedHashMap} is recommended when there is more than one
     * template, to ensure the map is traversed in order. To send records with a null
     * value, add a template with the {@link Void} class as a key; otherwise the first
     * template from the map values iterator will be used.
     * @param templates the {@link KafkaOperations}s to use for publishing.
     */
    public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(Map<Class<?>, KafkaOperations<? extends Object, ? extends Object>> templates) {
        this(templates, DEFAULT_DESTINATION_RESOLVER);
    }
```

Add a template configured for `byte[]` values (with a `ByteArraySerializer` on its producer) for the deserialization exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used that but tried to configure a message converter on the different kafka tempates which does not work because the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` does not send a `Message<?>` but a `ProducerRecord`. Therefore I had to configure the templates with completely new producer factories instead of the one auto-configured by spring boot.

Comment: That is correct; the DLPR is invoked at a much lower level (there is no`Message<?>` available).